# A function satisfies the equation $f(x+y) = f(x) f(y)$. Show that $f(x)$ is differentiable at all $x$, and determine its $f'(x)$ in terms of $f(x)$.

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0, \space f'(0) = c \space$ where $\space c \space$ is a constant and $\space f(x) \space$ is not equals to $0$.

Someone please help me. Im stuck on this question. I've no idea where to even start.

Comment: Try to use definition of derivative. It is not difficult. Please post your own efforts otherwise this runs the risk of closure.

Answer (score 1):

First show that $f(0)$ must be $1$ if $f$ is not the zero function. Then one has
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{y \to 0} \frac{{f(x + y) - f(x)}}{y} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{y \to 0} \frac{{f(x)f(y) - f(x)}}{y} = f(x)\mathop {\lim }\limits_{y \to 0} \frac{{f(y) - 1}}{y} = f(x)f'(0) =cf(x).
$$

Comment: How do you get f(0) = 1?

Comment: $f(0) = f(0 + 0) = f(0)f(0) = f^2 (0)$. So $f(0)$ is either $1$ or $0$. It cannot be $0$, since it would give $f(x)=f(x+0)=f(x)f(0)=f(x) \cdot 0 =0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Hi, why do we have to show that f(0) = 1 in the first place?

Comment: To get $(f(y)-1)/y = (f(y)-f(0))/y$, and so by definition, its limit at $y=0$ is the derivative of $f$ at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of a derivative. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, we need to study the limit:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

By the definition of the function, we know that $f(x+h) = f(x)f(h)$. So, we simplify the above:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x)(f(h)-1)}{h}$$

You mentioned that $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x = 0$ and that $f'(0) = c$. We also know that $f(x) \neq 0$. Now, I claim that $f(0) = 1$. Why? Consider:

$$f(0) = f(0+0) = f(0) \cdot f(0)$$

Since $f(0) \neq 0$, $f(0) = 1$. Since $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x = 0$, it is the case that:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x)(f(h)-1)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} f(x) \cdot \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$$

The second limit is just the derivative of $f(x)$ at $x = 0$ and the first one just evaluates to $f(x)$. So, we have:

$$f'(x) = f(x) \cdot c$$

And this proves that $f(x)$ is differentiable at any $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I should mention that it's always a good idea to start from the definitions of words and work through those definitions to try and get somewhere. It might not end up really working but this sort of experimenting is a very natural part of learning how to solve problems.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I still don't get how u got f(0) =1.

Comment: I used the definition of the given function. Think about it. We know that $0 + 0 = 0$. So: $f(0) = f(0+0)$. Since $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$, we have $f(0+0) = f(0) \cdot f(0)$. Then, we have to solve $f(0) = (f(0))^2$. One of the solutions to this is $f(0) = 0$ and the other is $f(0) = 1$. However, you mentioned that $f(x) \neq 0$ for any $x$. Hence, $f(0) \neq 0$. So, $f(0) = 1$. Does that make sense?